# Split fails without error

Tags: split, gzip, gunzip

How do you use the Linux command `split` to split a zip file into multiple smaller zip files?

I have a large zip archive that contains a single file containing millions of lines which I need to process. Fortunately, the processing can be done in parallel, so I want to split the zip into N parts to give to processors running on several machines.

I'm currently using this command to split a single massive zip archive into 10 smaller zip archives:

```
gunzip -c original.zip | split -l 10 - 'smaller-part-' --additional-suffix='.txt' --filter='gzip >> $FILE.zip'
```

On my localhost running Ubuntu 16, this runs perfectly. However, on another server running Ubuntu 16, this command mysteriously fails with the error:

```
split: with FILE=smaller-part-aa.txt, exit 1 from command: gzip >> $FILE.zip
```

Why is it exiting with an error code? Even if I specify `--verbose`, it provides no further explanation.

Edit: The issue seems to be related to the user running the command. On the server throwing the error, I'm running it as a custom `buildbot` user in a shell launched like `sudo -u buildbot bash`. However, all files and directories are owned by that user. When I run the command as the default ubuntu user, it runs correctly. Why would gunzip/split/gzip error when ran as a custom user?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my user had `/bin/false` set for its `SHELL` environment variable, which causes split's `--filter` param to fail, since it requires a valid shell to execute the filter command. Using `vipw` to change this to `/bin/bash` fixed it.